# Get certain elements of an array by its key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sure there's a function for this:

What I have:

```
$myArray = array( 'foo' => 123, 'bar' => 456, 'lou' => 789, 'wuh' => 'xyz' );
$iNeed = array( 'foo', 'lou' );
```

How can I get the key value pairs that `$iNeed`:

```
$output = super_magic_function( $iNeed, $myArray );
// output should be array( 'foo' => 123, 'lou' => 789 );
```

How is that `super_magic_function` called (native php if possible)

Comment: Why can`t you make it...?

Comment: Why don't you try something, and then if it does not work and you can't figure out why, we find that for you

Comment: @HenkJansen I've tried with ´array_intersect´ but got an empty array

Comment: @AmazingDreams `array_combine`s parameters must have equal number of elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$output = array_intersect_key($myArray, array_flip($iNeed));
```

If you need it as a function:

```
function super_magic_function($array, $required) {
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($required));
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 123
    [lou] => 789
)
```

Documentation: [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key), [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip)

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/74141)

Comment: Genius! That's what I'm searching for

Comment: Wow - the demo is the icing on the cake!

Comment: Haha. I'm glad to have been of help. Cheers :)